# Cannot resolve method placeholder in Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm new to Square's `Picasso` Image loading library. I'm just trying with static data with images to display in a gridView.

Here's the code where i'm getting error :

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load(images[i]).into(imageView).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Error :

> Cannot resolve method placeholder

I understand it doesn't able to find method `placeholder`, but i just copied the same thing from their official site & what made this doesn't work?

build.gradle (dependency : posted incase if there's issue with version)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As method `into` is void, it should be the last method called.

Look info here:
https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.java#L497

Try to exchange placeholder and into methods calls:

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load(images[i]).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I've to wait for some 6 minutes..idk why.